# Why does my MySQL server crash from this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a pretty straight-forward query that is crashing my MySQL server. When I run it, it loses the connection to MySQL and it takes the server a while to get back up.

For some reason, I get this when I run `SHOW FULL processlist` during the outage:

```
5   debian-sys-maint    localhost       Query   0   Opening tables  select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
```

I believe that that is something MySQL does, it's not my connection.

The query I'm running is the following:

```
SELECT 
    f.title,
    q.title,
    AVG(answer) AS average_answer,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS number_of_answers
FROM
    answers a
INNER JOIN forms f 
    ON f.id = a.form_id
INNER JOIN questions q
    ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE
    a.form_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY
    f.title,
    q.title;
```

(Please note that I changed the aliases and table names, so disregard any typos.)

The thing is that this works if I run the query without one of the 2 functions (`AVG` and `COUNT`). If I run them together, my connection dies.

The dataset I run this against would be ~12.000.000 records, but the `WHERE f.id IN(1,2,3)` limits the set to just 30 or 40. The WHERE-clause is fast, if I run `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE form_id IN (1,2,3)` I get the results in 0,01 seconds.

Why does this combination of functions make the server's head spin?

EDIT: 
This is the output of the EXPLAIN. It's kinda hard to get it formatted right though:

```
1   SIMPLE  f   range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4                   3   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  a   ref     form_fk,question_fk,fk_answer_quality   form_fk 5   f.id    16  Using where
1   SIMPLE  q   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   a.question_id   1
```

The problem appears to be in the first row, but I don't get the 'range' part.

Comment: Do u have an index on a.form_id?

Comment: It's a foreign key, so yes. As I added in the question, this: `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE form_id IN (1,2,3)` is done in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Have u tried using EXPLAIN SELECT to see how the database would optimize it?

Comment: Also, please post the output of EXPLAIN (Whole Querry) in the answer above. That would help us understand better.

Comment: What do u see under the column 'Rows' for the first row? Unclear because the output isn't formatted,

Comment: Just 3. 14 for the second and 1 for the third.

Comment: Hmm i really don't think its a problem with your query. It looks to be a problem with the server installation/table storage on the disc etc.

Comment: I've got 30 minutes to find out, before the rest of the team arrives and I can't let the dev server die over and over again anymore. :D

Comment: To make sure it isn't a problem with your query, you can replicate the schema of your 3 tables on sqlfiddle.com. No need to insert all rows. Just some 100 rows would be enough. You can export your sql and import it via copy pasting the sql there.

Comment: Did you manage to find out?

Comment: I'm trying to see if changing the datatype of the column makes any difference. The answer column is of type TEXT. I do exclude all non-digit answers in a WHERE-clause, but that's what I'm looking into now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.t1,
    a.t2,
    AVG(a.answer) AS average_answer,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS number_of_answers
from (
SELECT 
    f.title as t1,
    q.title as t2,
    answer,
    a.id
FROM
    answers a
INNER JOIN forms f 
    ON f.id = a.form_id
INNER JOIN questions q
    ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE
    a.form_id IN (1,2,3)
) a
GROUP BY a.t1, a.t2;
```